# Redraw map on OpenLayers 6?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I'm trying to redraw the Vector Layer in OpenLayers (version 6.1.1, latest is 6.2.1) but any sort of documentation on it is OpenLayers 3.  I've tried translating it myself, but either the redraw just isn't working properly or I'm writing the syntax incorrectly.  Does anyone have any idea how to go about this?

I haven't been able to get the icons to even flicker to show that they're updating, never mind getting them to update as the database gets filled up.  It's really important that I get the icons on my Vector Layer refreshing so anything and everything helps, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `refresh` method of the source should do what you want. Give it a try.

[OL API - Vector Source refresh](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#refresh)

Comment: Use `changed` method on a vector layers.

Comment: I'm integrating the FontStyle from ol-ext into a custom Angular library for OpenLayers. I've added code to refresh upon fonts being loaded - BUT it doesn't refresh the fonts when the layers are redrawn and I can see the fonts being downloaded by the browser, followed by the refresh calls for each vector layer. 
any thoughts :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

Credits to @viglino-jean-marc, as of `ol` v6.6.1 using `refresh` method of the `vector` source not working as intended, `changed` method is what do the job.